# How to auto-start an Electron app after a fresh installation?

Tags: electron, electron-builder, squirrel.windows

I am using Squirrel on windows to install my electron application. I have tried to run an application after a fresh installation, using a Squirrel event.

```
case '--squirrel-install': return app.quit()
```

I removed app.quit() so that the application persists after an installation. The problem is that if I do not quit the app right away, the installation process itself incurs an error on Windows.  How can I make sure that my application run promptly after a fresh installation?